# Drupal_set_message not working with error logging disabled?

Tags: drupal-7

Do I understand this correctly. If you disable "Error Logging" to the Screen, then Drupal doesn't display anything that should be displayed via drupal_set_message? Then how does one give feedback to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drupal_set_message works even if you have disabled the "Error Logging". Check if you have printed `$messages` variable in `page.tpl.php`

Comment: I do, but all messages disappear when I disable logging.

Comment: Check if user with id 0 exists in users table

Comment: Yip. it does. I will keep checking what else could be wrong.